# How to create a TFS 2010 SendEmailNotification handler

Tags: events, tfs

So I have recently moved my email to google apps and now require smtp authentication to send email from TFS.  Lo and behold: TFS doesn't support this feature.  As a workaround I tried setting up an SMTP relay on my TFS server but couldn't get it to work.  I figured instead I'd create a TFS event handler which could react to the event which is triggered in TFS.  So I have one question.  Where do I start?  I've never created any TFS extensions or anything like that.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably be best downloading the [TFS Event Handler](http://tfseventhandler.codeplex.com/) from codeplex which works with TFS 2010 as long as you install Team Explorer 2008 SP1 and if you need additional handlers you can [create your own](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/TFS_Event_Handler.aspx).

If you want to write your own handler from scratch then you need to deside wither you want to [handle SOAP events](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/HandlingTFSEvents.aspx)  like the [TFS Event Handler](http://tfseventhandler.codeplex.com/) or to write an [Event Sink](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/archive/2010/07/07/tfs-event-handler-for-team-foundation-server-2010.aspx).